# VS 2010 fails debugging: HttpException invalid file name for file monitoring in LoadControl

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've really been struggling for days on this matter.

I have migrated a asp.net 3.5 project in VS2010 to a asp.net 4 project. Everything worked fine for several weeks.

Somehow, I get a strange error since a few days. To clarify what this project looks like:

**The Application**

It's a UserControl based application and the app areas are composed of nested UserControl Hierarchies, that load their children Controls in `OnInit()`, in order to get the event system to work.

(Note: everything works great in VS2008 and .net 3.5!)

**The Error**

Now when I start debugging the webapplication in VS2010, sometimes (!!!), a HttpException is thrown, with the message:

> Invalid file name for file monitoring.

in `LoadControl()`<- and now it gets interesting, the parameter for LoadControl is a ~/ prefixed UserControl-Path eg. ~/Controls/Home/Partial.ascx BUT in the Exception it is shown as a Directory, somewhere in the Controls Directory.

Probably VS uses such an approach to internally track changed files to reload?

Has anyone encountered the same issue? If so, have there been any solutions?

**Edit**: when deploying the webapplication, the error vanishes. It only occurs when debugging. I have currently disabled HttpExceptions in the debug->exceptions menu. But i would be very glad to catch those again too ..

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error eventually happened again, but now i found that you can circumvent the issue by reverting the `Enable Just My Code` option in the Options: `Tools->Options->Debugging->General`, which in fact originally had introduced the broken debugging behavior.

The Option `Enable Just My Code` has to be set.

Comment: Not a solution, it just ignores the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that requires usage of reflection, that means that the website should be running under "Full Trust"

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Composite
{
    internal static class BuildManagerHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a user control. Prevents an exception that appears in Visual Studio while debugging
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="virtualPath"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Type GetCompiledType(string virtualPath)
        {
            try
            {
                DisableUrlMetadataCaching(true);

                return System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(virtualPath);
            }
            finally
            {
                DisableUrlMetadataCaching(false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disabling the "url metadata caching" prevents <see cref="System.Web.HttpException" /> in debugger 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disableCaching"></param>
        public static void DisableUrlMetadataCaching(bool disableCaching)
        {
            #if DEBUG

            var systemWeb = typeof (System.Web.TraceMode).Assembly;
            Type cachedPathData = systemWeb.GetType("System.Web.CachedPathData", false);
            if (cachedPathData == null) return;

            FieldInfo field = cachedPathData.GetField("s_doNotCacheUrlMetadata", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (field == null) return;

            field.SetValue(null, disableCaching);

            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I had this problem for many years

Comment: How do you integrate this into your application?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I call `DisableUrlMetadataCaching` in a `try/finally` around all calls to `BuildManager` in my code, including `BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath` and `TemplateControl.LoadControl` and `TemplateControl.LoadTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and already had `Enable Just My Code` checked in VS. However after unchecking the option, saving settings, and then re-checking it, the issue went away.