# Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'E:\sitesroot\0\CustomControls'. Common reasons for failure include

Tags: azure

My application was migrated from ASP.net to Azure. While running in the Compute Emulator it gives the following exception:

```
Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()
{"Response is not available in this context."}
    [System.Web.HttpException]: {"Response is not available in this context."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Response is not available in this context."
    Source: "System.Web"

    StackTrace: "   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Response()\r\n   at Writehome_aspxToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declare
dType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WritePlaceHolderToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.S
erializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfControlToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , Collection
DataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDec
laredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   a
t System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteSerializableSessionStateStoreDataToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContract contract, Hashtable surrogateDataContracts)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWr
iteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.NetDataContractCacheObjectSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object value)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheObjectSerializationProvider.SerializeUserObject(Object userObject, Boolean isCompressionEnabled, ValueFlagsVersion flagsType)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SerializeValue(Object obj)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle,
 TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalPutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass9c.<PutAndUnlock>b__9b()\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MonitoringListenerFactory.EmptyListener.Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.IMonitoringListener.Listen[TResult](Func`1 innerDelegate)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheWrapper.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<PutAndUnlock>b__1b()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFo
rwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass31`1.<PerformCacheOperation>b__30()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheRetryWrapper.PerformCacheOperation(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PerformCacheOperation[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.BlobBasedSessionStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContextBase context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Exec
ute()\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)"
    TargetSite: {System.Web.HttpResponse get_Response()}
```

So I tried by deploying it in the Azure Subscription withe IntelliTrace log, So it show the following exception,

```
System.Web.HttpException

Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'E:\sitesroot\0\CustomControls'. Common reasons for failure include:
The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
The filename is not a absolute path.
The filename contains wildcard characters.
The file specified is a directory.
Access denied.

Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'E:\sitesroot\0\MasterPages. Common reasons for failure include:
The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
The filename is not a absolute path.
The filename contains wildcard characters.
The file specified is a directory.
Access denied.
```

Comment: Having 'Enable Just My Code' under Tools/Options/Debugging/General checked made it disappear in my case. No idea why the exception was thrown when having it unchecked though.

Answer (score 1):

as per [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/dff3d7fa-5264-4f8d-af1e-19e1c132bd10)

> Not a solution at all, But Clearing all my temp files
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4\Temporary ASP.NET Files (or
>   something close enough) - **might work**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to clear my temp files. But the same error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer in the comments above worked for me. And I'm not even using Azure, just trying to debug an asp.net mvc4 project.

> Having 'Enable Just My Code' under Tools/Options/Debugging/General checked made it disappear in my case.

Comment: That should be enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the temp files did not work for me as there were no temp files in that folder...lol!  Having the API not throw exceptions from System.Web.HttpException is a work around, however these errors are still there eating up processes in the background.  It's really bad practice to sweep bugs under the rug.

[found this related post on stackoverflow which may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565280/vs-2010-fails-debugging-httpexception-invalid-file-name-for-file-monitoring-in)