# Exception in bundles on application startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I've got an ASP.NET MVC Application. All scripts are in bundle as usual. Here is my code from BundleConfig.cs

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/public-js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",

                    "~/Scripts/string.utilities.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/google-charts-loader.js",
                    "~/Scripts/biz/core/app-config.js",

                    "~/Scripts/public/core/db-api.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/app.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/directives.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/controller-helpers.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/public-controller-helpers.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/services.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/list-controller.js",
                    "~/Scripts/public/core/item-controller.js",

                    "~/Scripts/n.utilities.biz.js"
                    ));
```

According IntelliTrace i've got an exception that was caugth and handled by system. Here is exception description is

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll (": Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'C:\IISTest\SuperMVC\Scripts\public'. Common reasons for failure include: 
- The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
- The filename is not an absolute path.
- The filename contains wildcard characters.
- The file specified is a directory.
- Access denied.)
```

Application continue to works fine with no errors. 
Why this error appears on application startup?

Comment: Are the bundled items included?

Comment: I think this can help you out to suppress this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565280/vs-2010-fails-debugging-httpexception-invalid-file-name-for-file-monitoring-in You need to enable "Just My Code" in VS Debugger options

Comment: Yep. All bundled items are included

Comment: Is this doing on your local machine or server?

Comment: it's on local machine

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it throws not by user(your) application code. Did you hit a point in `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Enable Just My Code`? Also there is one interesting place with CLR exceptions: `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> CLR Exceptions` It is for VS2015.